# Change Navigation Drawer selected item from within Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer in my main activity, and 2 fragments (A and B). The Navigation has two items (A and B). When the application is started the main activity shows and displays fragment A in the FrameLayout.

Fragment A contains a button that replaces the FrameLayout content to Fragment B. The .replace works fine, but I'm not sure how to change the selected drawer item from A to B.

Jayesh helped me with this... didn't realize it was easy. For those interested in my main activity (which hosts the navigation drawer):

```
public static void changeDrawerItem(int Position) {
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(1, true);
}
```

Note: mDrawerList is my Drawer List. Not sure if this is the best way to change the item, but it'll allow me to change the drawer item from other fragments I create.

In the fragment I simply call the method with

```
MainActivity.changeDrawerItem(1);
```

Comment: So you are using the fragment manager which is in the activity to replace Fragment A with B right ?

Comment: that is correct. fragment manager is what i'm using to redirect (or replace) the framelayout.

Comment: By any chance if you are using the navigation drawer example from the developers.android website, I think you already have an instance of your navigation drawer in your activity. You could write a method in your navigation drawer and invoke this method from your activity.

Comment: i'm a dummy... didn't realize it was that easy. Thanks Jayesh! I created a public static method in my main activity and passed the position of the drawer item.

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil why do you have to create a static method just for this? you could have easily create a Public Method in your activity and access it via the fragment , since your current fragment is already have an attachment to your current Activity instance?. Please Correct me if i missed anything